# In Solr 7.2, automatic language detection was set up to enable seamless search in language-specific fields without explicitly specifying the language

Tags: java, solr

In Solr 7.2, I configured the solr-config and managed schema to enable multilingual indexing of files or documents. The objective was to implement automatic language detection during search, allowing Solr to search in the appropriate language-specific fields seamlessly, without the need for explicit language specification. For instance, when searching for "author:تجربة", Solr should automatically search in the "author_ar" field, which is designed for the Arabic language and indicated by the "_ar" suffix in the dynamic field of type "text_ar".

However, it seems that there is an issue with the search results. When searching for "author:تجربة" (without a space), it does not return the expected results. Surprisingly, adding a space between the colon and the search term, like "author: تجربة" (with a space), does return the desired results.

Solution to solve the searching problem

Comment: I would suggest running both queries with the parameter `debug=all` and see why is the parser interpreting differently. More info: https://hectorcorrea.com/blog/2021-11-16/solr-debugquery